# Evaluate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3 \vec{p} \frac{e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}}{(|\vec{p}|+a)(m^2 + |\vec{p}-\vec{p}_1|^2)} $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help with the following integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3 \vec{p} \frac{e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}}{(|\vec{p}|+a)(m^2 + |\vec{p}-\vec{p}_1|^2)} $$

where both $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{p}_1$ are arbitrary three-dimensional vectors, and $a$ is a positive number.

Update: Previously I oversimplified my original problem. The integral in my previous question was

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3 \vec{p} \frac{e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}}{m^2 + |\vec{p}-\vec{p}_1|^2}  $$

Comment: Please put your previously asked integral in the question and put the updated integral in the update as Andrei answered your originally asked integral.

Answer (score 1):

First do a change of variable $\vec q=\vec p-\vec p_1$, so your integral becomes $$e^{i\vec p_1\vec x}\int_{\mathbb R^3}d^3\vec q\frac{e^{i\vec q\vec x}}{m^2+q^2}$$
Then change to polar coordinates, with $\theta$ measured from the $\vec x$ axis.
$$e^{i\vec p_1\vec x}\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\int_0^\infty q^2dq\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta\frac{e^{iqx\cos\theta}}{m^2+q^2}$$